# MasterPage links, ASP.net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Well, I have an ASP.net project with a MasterPage, at first I used in all my links the '../' and '~/' sign because I wanted it to always be relative to the root but it didn't work as good as i want it because there were pages in sub-directories that didn't recognized that. I found another solution by adding a base tag on the head and getting the root URL from ASP.net, but another problem came up. All the ASP.net Server Controls with Post-Back, Posted-Back to the root.
Does anybody know how can i make all the links be relative to the root but the server control's Post-Back.

B.T.W: I can't go MVC, it's a project for school.

Comment: are you using the friendly Url?

Comment: no, I use normal ASP.net URL's no URL Rewritres

Comment: ok are you keeping this link to image tags?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i mean , how are your urls appended ? to anchor tags or to img?

Comment: both,  href/src and base tag

Comment: just add runat="server" to those tags and  use '~/'

Comment: thanks, what about js?

Comment: js means? elaborate more

Comment: well if i have ajax posts on JavaScript in the MasterPage how can i put a relative link(to root)?

Comment: it does not work with script tags as well, i have tried now, that makes them c# server code. (js script links)

Comment: Post your codehere please

Comment: I posted the code.